Link Azure Repo pull request retrospectively to work item
I've created a couple of small pull requests in Azure Repos.  However, I forgot to link them to the relevant work items, so the pull requests have failed their checks.  It looks like it should be easy to retrospectively link a pull request to a work item but it's not working for me.
On the taskboard I have a user story, Id 200258, with a sub-task, Id 214388:

When I attempt to link the pull request to a work item, however, it only shows a few work items in the Work items dropdown list:

and if I enter the Id I want to find, it can't find it:

The work item I want to find actually flashes up in the dropdown list momentarily, before the No items found message appears.
Is there any way to link the pull request to a work item that doesn't appear in the Work item dropdown list?

I would suggest you have a test with the Azure DevOps CLI az repos pr work-item add to Link one or more work items to a pull request.
Here is a sample PowerShell script for your reference.
$orgName = "YourADOOrgName"
$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = "xxxxxx"
$prId = 106

az repos pr work-item add --id $prId --work-items 2347 2348 --org https://dev.azure.com/$orgName



Worked perfectly, thank you

For anyone looking to use this method, environment variable $env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT is set to your Axure DevOps personal access token (PAT). To set a PAT see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#create-a-pat
